# How to using grouping sets to create Total?

Tags: sql

I always thought you can using grouping sets to create a total. But that does not work:

```
SELECT 
       ISNULL([BusinessType], 'TOTAL') as [BusinessType]
      ,count(distinct concat([ProductLine], BankName))
FROM [AdventureWorksDW2019].[dbo].[DimReseller]
GROUP BY GROUPING sets
   (BusinessType, () )
```

I got this results:

[image: results]

Do someone understand why that do not work. Why **()** at grouping sets does not create a total? It seems it does not work every time.

Answer (score 0):

You need use grouping_id func to check your total or subtotal groups. In my example (MS SQL Server) I used rollup instead of grouping sets. But you may use it if you want.

```
with productsTransactions as (
select 00 transaction_id, 'Womens Wear' category, 'Separates' subcategory, 'sep1' prodName, 10 cnt union all
select 01 transaction_id, 'Womens Wear' category, 'Separates' subcategory, 'sep1' prodName, 15 cnt union all
select 02 transaction_id, 'Womens Wear' category, 'Separates' subcategory, 'sep2' prodName,  5 cnt union all
select 03 transaction_id, 'Womens Wear' category, 'Separates' subcategory, 'sep2' prodName,  7 cnt union all
select 04 transaction_id, 'Womens Wear' category, 'Separates' subcategory, 'sep3' prodName, 21 cnt union all
select 05 transaction_id, 'Womens Wear' category, 'Separates' subcategory, 'sep3' prodName, 54 cnt union all
--
select 06 transaction_id, 'Womens Wear' category, 'Swimwear'  subcategory, 'swim1' prodName,  2 cnt union all
select 07 transaction_id, 'Womens Wear' category, 'Swimwear'  subcategory, 'swim1' prodName,  5 cnt union all
select 08 transaction_id, 'Womens Wear' category, 'Swimwear'  subcategory, 'swim2' prodName,  7 cnt union all
select 09 transaction_id, 'Womens Wear' category, 'Swimwear'  subcategory, 'swim2' prodName,  2 cnt union all
select 10 transaction_id, 'Womens Wear' category, 'Swimwear'  subcategory, 'swim3' prodName, 11 cnt union all
select 11 transaction_id, 'Womens Wear' category, 'Swimwear'  subcategory, 'swim3' prodName, 32 cnt union all
--
select 12 transaction_id, 'Mens Wear'   category, 'Sports'    subcategory, 'sp1'   prodName, 32 cnt union all
select 13 transaction_id, 'Mens Wear'   category, 'Sports'    subcategory, 'sp1'   prodName, 10 cnt union all
select 14 transaction_id, 'Mens Wear'   category, 'Sports'    subcategory, 'sp2'   prodName, 30 cnt union all
select 15 transaction_id, 'Mens Wear'   category, 'Sports'    subcategory, 'sp2'   prodName, 24 cnt union all
select 16 transaction_id, 'Mens Wear'   category, 'Sports'    subcategory, 'sp3'   prodName, 12 cnt union all
select 17 transaction_id, 'Mens Wear'   category, 'Sports'    subcategory, 'sp3'   prodName, 43 cnt union all
--
select 18 transaction_id, 'Mens Wear'   category, 'Swimwear'  subcategory, 'swim1' prodName, 12 cnt union all
select 19 transaction_id, 'Mens Wear'   category, 'Swimwear'  subcategory, 'swim1' prodName, 15 cnt union all
select 20 transaction_id, 'Mens Wear'   category, 'Swimwear'  subcategory, 'swim2' prodName, 17 cnt union all
select 21 transaction_id, 'Mens Wear'   category, 'Swimwear'  subcategory, 'swim2' prodName, 12 cnt union all
select 22 transaction_id, 'Mens Wear'   category, 'Swimwear'  subcategory, 'swim3' prodName, 31 cnt union all
select 23 transaction_id, 'Mens Wear'   category, 'Swimwear'  subcategory, 'swim3' prodName, 52 cnt
)
select
  grouping_id(category, subcategory) grp_id,
  case grouping_id(category, subcategory)    
    when 0 then 'Subcategory total'  
    when 1 then 'Category total'
    when 3 then 'Total'
   end grp_name, 
  category,
  subcategory,
  count(distinct prodName) as prodName,
  sum(cnt)                 as ProductLineSum
from productsTransactions
group by rollup(category, subcategory)
order by 1,2,3;

grp_id  |grp_name            |category        |subcategory    |prodName   |ProductLineSum
--------+--------------------+----------------+---------------+-----------+---------------
0       |Subcategory total   |Mens Wear       |Sports         |3          |151
0       |Subcategory total   |Mens Wear       |Swimwear       |3          |139
0       |Subcategory total   |Womens Wear     |Swimwear       |3          |59
0       |Subcategory total   |Womens Wear     |Separates      |3          |112
1       |Category total      |Mens Wear       |null           |6          |290
1       |Category total      |Womens Wear     |null           |6          |171
3       |Total               |null            |null           |9          |461
```

You may use groping sets if you want. Result will be the same.

```
group by grouping sets ((category, subcategory), (category), ())
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/UQMzXq-F

Read more about [groping_id function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), [rollup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#group-by-rollup), [groping sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#group-by-grouping-sets--).